# Maintenance manual

Tags: car

I recently started working as an aircraft technician and quickly learnt that for all things related to maintenance there is a chapter in a book called a maintenance manual.

I assume that for cars there is something similar and I was wondering what it is called.

I don't have a specific car model in mind (though I'm looking into getting a Hyundai volestor) just a general question, if I do have a car of any model what manual am I to look into for all problems, repairs and annual check-ups.
My intention is to be able to repair my own car especially because mechanics in my country are expensive and sometimes incompetent.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

There are indeed maintenance manuals available for most cars - there's several publishers who do them, notably Haynes and Chilton, and there's usually an official one done by the manufacturer - this official one isn't normally available to the general public, but can often be found second-hand, particularly for older cars.

The easiest option is to search for "  workshop manual" on your favourite search engine.

Comment: You can often purchase the Official Workshop Manual from the dealer for most, at least the European makes, the Asian ones may not be so forthcoming. I have purchased Official Workshop manuals for Jaguar, Ford, Ford Tractors, John Deere just to name a few...

Comment: Once you've used an official Workshop Manual, you always feel short-changed if you ever have to work with the Haynes/Chilton version afterwards.. :)

Comment: Also known as a _Factory Service Manual_ (FSM for short).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site @EliezerCohen, as a pilot it's good to see people are still getting into aircraft maintenance. Cars have maintenance manuals the same as airplanes, with repair procedures, exploded view diagrams, etc. They may be called maintenance manuals, or garage manuals. Nowadays they are much more likely to be online. These manuals are not always made available to the general public, or they may not be free, but if you dig you might be able to find a copy. It all depends on the make and model.

There are also independently produces manuals for many cars, Haynes Owner Workshop Manuals are the most common, and contain many procedures for common maintenance, sometimes going as far as engine tear-down procedures. I almost always buy the Haynes manual for my cars as they contain valuable information in one place, the web is also a fantastic resource as chances are someone else has had your problem.